# Named Parameters and the params keyword in C#

Tags: c#, .net, named-parameters

I have a C# method with a variable length argument list declared using the `params` keyword:

```
public void VariableLengthParameterFunction (object firstParam, 
                                             params object[] secondParam)
```

Is there any way of using named parameters when calling the method?

Comment: what do you wish to accomplish?

Comment: just trying to use named parameters without having to change the method signature

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can call it using named parameter like this:

```
VariableLengthParameterFunction(
    secondParam: new object[] { 5, 7, 3, 2 }, 
    firstParam: 4);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with msbuild tools 2015, the secondparam is lost if you use the shorthand for a single element? (works with devenv though)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I assumed you want to access the `params object[] secondParam` array using named parameters.

Currently only the code inside the method knows what `secondParam` may contain. From just the method signature there's no link between the `object[]` and names/types for each element within that array.

Furthermore, since you're using the `params` keyword, there is no way of supplying `secondParam[1]` without supplying a value for `secondParam[0]` (or `null`).

Perhaps you could create an overload which takes named parameters, and which creates the `object[]` and then calls this method. Or the other way around.

Comment: that's a good point , but using the ``` params ``` keyword we already know there will be just a bunch of input with no special order , so it wouldn't be necessary.